# How to print #(sharp sign) in a Makefile

Tags: makefile, escaping

Suppose you have a variable which is set as:

```
AVar = "#"

echo "${AVar}"
```

The above thing does not output in Makefile when run through make.

# must be escaped but the AVar may not have special chars in its content?

So what can I escape the Avar?

Answer (score 2):

Tested working with GNU Make 3.81 on MacOS X:

```
AVar = "\#"

foo:
    @echo "${AVar}"
```

I'm not sure what you mean by "AVar may not have special chars in its content".  In this case it's the only way to tell `make` that the `#` is part of the string, and not the start of a comment.

Comment: I mean when you have AVar = "#" without "\" escape. will #echo "${Avar}" work?

Comment: @whoi no, that won't work, because it thinks the `#` is the start of a comment, even though it's inside a string. With GNU make you end up with `AVar = " foo: @echo "` followed by `${Avar}"`.  The unterminated quote in that final bit causes a syntax error.